# Attaching Typeahead row with anchor tag

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using ajax call to populate data in my dropdown using Typeahead`, now the HTML Typeahead creates for every row in dropdown look like

```
<li class="active" data-value="xx">
    <a href="#">
        my Text
    </a>
</li>
```

My requirement is to have some value in anchor tag where when user clicks on dropdown text, it takes user to new page.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `updater` attribute in `Typeahead` as code in updater gets called on click of row in `Typeahead` dropdown.

**code**

```
updater: function (item) {            
       // do whatever you want to do here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bind. On select redirect to the link you want

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {

```
//Your typeahead code lies here
```

}
).bind("typeahead:selected", function(obj, datum, name) {

```
window.location.href = ''; //redirect

console.log(obj, datum, name);
```

});